# React: How to alert a list, based off the value of inputs

Tags: reactjs

I am making a [React app](https://codesandbox.io/s/expense-tracker-7dyor) that tracks your expenses. Right now in the ExpenseInput component I want to be able to extract the values of the inputs and alert the values that were entered. Later on I will want to render a list of expenses similar to a ToDo App. I have some stuff setup already. I know that the expense state variable should store all you expenses and all the other state variables are set to its respective inputs. I just am not sure what the next step should be.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function ExpenseInputs() {
  const [expense, setExpense] = useState([]);
  const [expenseName, setExpenseName] = useState("");
  const [expenseAmt, setExpenseAmt] = useState();
  const [expenseType, setExpenseType] = useState("");
  const expenseTypes = ["Food", "Gas", "Entertainment", "Rent"];

  const updateExpenseName = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setExpenseName(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  const updateExpenseAmt = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setExpenseAmt(e.target.value);
  };

  const addExpenses = () => {

  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Expense</label>
        <input
          value={expenseName}
          onChange={updateExpenseName}
          className="expense-input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Expense"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Amount</label>
        <input
          value={expenseAmt}
          onChange={updateExpenseAmt}
          className="expense-amount"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Expense amount"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Expense Type</label>
        <select>
          {expenseTypes.map(e => {
            return <option>{e}</option>;
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <button onClick={addExpenses} className="button">
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your values in the state of each input (expenseAmt, expenseName, etc).

```
  const [expenseName, setExpenseName] = useState("");
  const [expenseAmt, setExpenseAmt] = useState();
  const [expenseType, setExpenseType] = useState("");
```

For your purposes to add new expense you can use the state which may be array of objects, where each object represents your expense (title, type, amount).

```
const [expense, setExpense] = useState([]);
```

So you need to create handler to add new object to your array of expenses.

```
  const addExpenses = () => {

  };
```

And just map it. Then you pass object of expense to each expense component as props.

```
      {expense.map((expense, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index} expense={expense} />
      ))}
```

For removing you need to create remove handler and pass it to expense component as props and fire it there.

[image: Edit Expense Tracker]

Comment: So just for my understanding how exactly does the   const addExpenses = () => {

  }; work? I know that the prevState argument holds the value of the state. But why do you use a spread over the prevState array?

Comment: @faizan_khan98 Because when updating state you need to return new value rather than change the existing one. When react decides whether to re-render component or not it checks the previous state and the new one. In this case, we have an array, so what react is seeing is a reference to it, not what is inside it. So if you change the value inside the array, react see that previous state was not changed (the reference to an array still the same) and decides to stay still. This concept calls immutability.

Comment: @faizan_khan98 In this case, I return an array that contains a shallow-copy (via spread operator) of the previous one and add a new values to it.

Comment: So the ...prevState is what allows React to create a new copy of the useState([]) and passes in the value that was held in prevState?

Comment: @faizan_khan98 This is not necessarily React, but JS overall. Learn more about destructuring and spread/rest operator. Basically, what I did here is returning a new array [] and copy previous values from the state [...prevState] then added some new values after [..prevState, newValues].